# Create dictionary from CSV without repeating top level

Tags: python

I am trying to make an API using a script.  It runs but I need to make it iterate the CSV file without appending `port_config` to each line:

Reading this CSV File:

```
device_id,port,description
4444,eth1/1,test1
1111,eth1/2,test2
2222,eth1/3,test3
1234,eth1/4,test4
```

The code I have so far:

```
for device_id,port,description in devices:
    print(device_id,port,description)
    payload="{\n \"port_config\": { \"%s\": { \"description\": \"%s\"                      
             }\n}\n}" % (port,description)
    print(payload)
```

Result of above:

```
{
 "port_config": { "interfacex/x": { "description": "test1" }
}
}
{
 "port_config": { "interfacex/x": { "description": "test2" }
}
}
{
 "port_config": { "interfacex/x": { "description": "test3" }
}
}
{
 "port_config": { "interfacex/x": { "description": "test4" }
}
}
```

Desired results:

```
{
    "port_config": {
        "eth1/1": {"description": "test0,"},
        "eth1/2": {"description": "test1,"},
        "eth1/3": {"description": "test2,"},
        "eth1/4": {"description": "test3,"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better question, thanks for putting the effort in to get it into shape.

Comment: Appreciate your help with this.  I am new to this so lots to learn still.  Next time I'll try to do better in the first shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question still has one problem. The CSV example doesn't exactly match the desired output. Let's say you have the following CSV string.

```py
devices = """device_id,port,description
4444,eth1/1,test1
1111,eth1/2,test2
2222,eth1/3,test3
1234,eth1/4,test4
"""
```

And you want the following output:

```
d = {
    "port_config": {
        "eth1/1": {"description": "test1,"},
        "eth1/2": {"description": "test2,"},
        "eth1/3": {"description": "test3,"},
        "eth1/4": {"description": "test4,"},
    }
}
```

You can easily achieve this in Python by doing some dictionary gymnastics like the following:

```py
import csv
from pprint import pprint

# Input csv.
devices = """device_id,port,description
4444,eth1/1,test1
1111,eth1/2,test2
2222,eth1/3,test3
1234,eth1/4,test4
"""

# Read the data using Python's built-in csv module.
lines = devices.splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(lines)
devices = list(reader)

# Let's initialize the target payloads data structure.
payload = {
    "port_config": {},
}

for idx, (device_id, port, description) in enumerate(devices):
    if idx == 0:
        continue # This line skips the header.
    payload["port_config"][port] = {"description": description}

pprint(payload)
```

This should give you the following output:

```
{'port_config': {'eth1/1': {'description': 'test1'},
                 'eth1/2': {'description': 'test2'},
                 'eth1/3': {'description': 'test3'},
                 'eth1/4': {'description': 'test4'}}}
```

Comment: So the "device_id" portion I was using that for something else that is why it is not in the desired result.  I couldn't quite understand "lines = devices.splitlines()" part but I read the file using "open" and then rest is the same.  So I'm getting the desired results now just gotta get the PUT working.  I think it may be because instead of getting double quotes I am getting single quotes which may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via pandas also -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('inp_file.csv')
result = {'port_config' : {item['port'] :{"description": item['description']} for item in df[['port','description']].to_dict(orient='records')}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a shot too and see how that works.  Will post the update.

Comment: @Ali sure, no problem :)